# Dependency property propagation failing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, dependency-properties

I made a UserControl called ObjectExplorer :

```
public partial class ObjectExplorer : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(List<Node>), typeof(ObjectExplorer), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Node>(), ItemsSet));
    public List<Node> Items
    {
        get { return (List<Node>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Inside the XAML of the control it has :

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Padding="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,3" ContextMenu="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NodeTypeToContextMenuConverter}}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Padding="4,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So we can see, the TreeView is bound to the Items DP. Now I am using it in my MainWindow.xaml like so :

```
<fe:ObjectExplorer x:Name="objExplorer" Items="{Binding DatabaseObjects}" />
```

So this "instance" of the control, its Items is bound to the DP on MainWindow :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseObjectsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabaseObjects", typeof(List<Node>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Node>(), DatabaseObjectsPropertySet));
    public List<Node> DatabaseObjects
    {
        get { return (List<Node>)GetValue(DatabaseObjectsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DatabaseObjectsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Inside a method on MainWindow.cs I am doing :

```
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
nodes.add(....);
DatabaseObjects = nodes;
```

**What happens :**

The DP on MainWindow triggers its set callback fine.

**What does not happen :**

The DP on ObjectExplorer does not get called, and nothing is displayed in the TreeView. I got it to work by naming the instance of the custom control (objExplorer) in mainwindow, then manually setting its Items whenever the callback for DatabaseObjects triggers...

```
private static void DatabaseObjectsPropertySet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainWindow)d).objExplorer.Items = (List<Node>)e.NewValue;
}
```

I would like to know... why?

EDIT:

The MainWindow's DataContext is set in XAML `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

I expect :

```
Code in MainWindow -> MainWindow.DatabaseObjects DP ||breaks|| ---(binding)--> objExplorer.Items ---> UC.Items ---(Internal Binding)--> TreeView.ItemSource
```

Comment: The `DatabaseObjects` binding in your MainWindow needs a source object. One option is to set the MainWindow's DataContext to itself, e.g. in its constructor: `DataContext = this;`.

Comment: @Clemens that is already the case `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` is set at the top of MainWindow's XAML file

Comment: You might mention that in your question.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you have made a common mistake in the declaration of your dependency properties. You should not set the default value of a mutable reference type DP by property metadata. All instances of the type that declares the property will use the same default object, here the same List<Node>.